# Why does my Acer 4310 run so slowly with Ubuntu 12.04 when it was lightening fast with Ubuntu 10.?

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, laptop, acer

Since I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Acer 4310 laptop I have noticed that the system freezes on occasions and the screen showing the program I am running shows a grey colour. I have done a clean install of Ubuntu and it still happens. One person said that either my 80GB hard drive is not enough or I need more RAM (I have 512mb). I did notice when I reinstalled Ubuntu 12.04 for the second time as a clean install it did say that it was using the whole drive, but of course i didn't believe it. Are there any diagnostic tools I can use to check???

Comment: your hard drive isn't the issue as long as It doesn't have any bad sectors. can you give the output for `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and `cat /proc/meminfo`

Comment: When I had **10.04 LTS** on an Acer 43xx laptop, I installed 1GB RAM (and it ran Ok).

Comment: These are low specs to run Unity smoothly. You'd be better off looking at alternatives like **Lubuntu** or **Xubuntu**

Comment: I guess 512MB of RAM could be a little insufficient. Do you have the possibility to install another 512MB?

Answer (score 0):

The bare minimum of system requirements rarely leads to a acceptable level of performance.

Things you can easily do to increase performance include:

A) Adding more RAM

B) Replacing the hard drive with one that packs more data onto a single track (higher capacity) or one with a faster rotational speed (a 7200 RPM drive will typically outperform a 5400 or 4200 RPM drive for obvious reasons).

C) Replacing the hard drive with a SSD (this approach will not only increase performance by being limited only by the speed of your interface (SATA-150) but also by drastically reducing seek time from 10's of ms to a fraction of a ms as there are no moving parts (heads to reposition to the appropriate track)